# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'seaborn'. How to redirect path in Python to capture libraries?

Tags: python, path, pip

on a Mac, I have pip3'd installed a few libraries in python. When I try to 'import', for example, seaborn, I receive a "module not found error." How can connect to the proper path? What is the "PATH" referred to in screenshot?
[image]

the issues appears to be synching library with proper path. Already installed libraries, but they will NOT import under python import command, says the following
[image]

Comment: To be honest, this doesn't look as if your PATH was set-up incorrectly since these are only warnings not related to the import. Did you install seaborn correctly (`pip install seaborn`)?

Comment: Please add your code and errors as text to the question, not as images.

Answer (score 0):

`PATH` is the environment variable on your system where all programs and scripts are located, which can be directly executed from the terminal/cmd/shell.

If you had a program called `myProgram.exe` in `C:\Users\Me\Desktop\`, you could add `C:\Users\Me\Desktop\` to the `PATH` variable and execute the program using

```
myProgram
```

in the terminal. Otherwise, you would have to include the path like:

```
C:\Users\Me\Desktop\myProgram.exe
```

You can edit this variable like described with nice pictures [here](https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10)

To execute python and pip from the console, you should have `C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37` (or wherever you installed Python to) in your path variable :)

Comment: sorry, I am on a mac. Thanks

Comment: @Jones On MacOS, you can edit `/etc/paths` and add your folder to this list :) Sorry, didn't see it at the first time

Comment: @TheCloclTwister that is an absolutely TERRIBLE idea.

Comment: very sorry (new at this), but where would I put the /etc/paths?

Comment: @MattDMo I'm sorry, I have never owned any Apple product. What's the proper procedure?

Comment: The proper procedure would be to append to one of your dotfiles in your home directory. Unless you know *exactly* what you're doing, you **never** want to touch system files such as those in `/etc`, `/proc`, `/usr`, and so on. There are plenty of questions on [su], [apple.se], and [unix.se] on how to modify your `PATH` on macOS.

Comment: thanks, all. Working this all day & cannot fix. Dejected, will try tomorrow